# Setting up Jekyll site

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll, github-pages

I am setting up a Jekyll blog hosted on GitHub Pages and I've run into an issue.  I'm using [this theme](http://aigarsdz.github.io/brume/) and I've downloaded the source code and am hosting it on my github [here](http://int-a.github.io) why does my site not have the same border art and such? It looks like the files are there, and the animations are even working, but the images are not showing up. My source code is [here](https://github.com/int-A/int-A.github.io), any idea why these images are not showing?

Also, if I wanted to add another section to my site, maybe a page labeled "thoughts" and include another link to that at the top where would I have to do that in the source code? I know I'd have to make another html page for it and then add the button in the code somewhere, but I haven't even been able to find where the current "Home" and "About" buttons come from.

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

Your site lacks a `main.css`. Viewing the page in Chrome shows:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://int-a.github.io/public/css/main.css
```

Attempting to view the contents of the `main.css` file referred to in your main page displays a clever(?) 404 message indicating the content has been stolen.

Looking at the site source shows the existence of a `/public/css/main.scss` rather than `main.css`.

And the top navbar contents are defined in `_includes/navigation.html` as defined in and created from site.data.links which appear under your `_data` directory.

Comment: huh, oh yeah. I see a main.scss in that folder, can I get it to look at that instead? scss is Sass, right?  Or have a main.css that points to main.scss?  It seems like main.scss is trying to accomplish what a main.css would

Comment: You'll need to run your *.scss files through a Sass-to-CSS compiler.

Comment: One thing you'll want to take note of is that Github Pages uses Jekyll version 1.5.1 while the Jekyll online documentation refers to version 2.*. I've informed Github of the discrepancy (they point you to the newer docs) so perhaps they will update their version.

Comment: Ok, cool. I'll check this out. Thank you!  And yeah, I'm not so sure about that 404 message, haha.

Comment: FYI, Jekyll 2.0 currently supports processing native Sass files, however GitHub pages as of today is not running Jekyll 2.0 yet. Once it is bumped to that, you're .scss file should be sufficient. To track progress on updating GH pages to Jekyll 2.0, see this thread: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/pull/63